# Current Blockchain Size CLI Command?

Tags: blockchain

What's the quickest way to find the current blockchain size of the chain you're on?  I am sure there are ways to look up an authoritative size for ETH.

EDIT: Apparently I wasn't clear.  I am not curious about the size of the file on disk.  I want to know the size of the blockchain *without* downloading it.  I want to know the size of blockchains for currencies I am NOT running a client for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that this is not possible, based on lots of research.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can use `du -sh` where `-s` is the sum and `-h` is a human readable output.

```
 ~ $ du -hs ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/
10G /home/user/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/
 ~ $ du -hs ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/expanse/
697M    /home/user/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/expanse/
```

This works for parity, all chains are in a labelled subdirectory of the `chains/` dir.

Comment: I've edited my post.  I'm not asking about the size of the blockchain on disk.  I'm asking about the size of the blockchain for blockchains I don't have on disk.

Comment: There is no way for your client to know that.

Comment: Fine.  I assumed as much.  But what other ways are there to know that?